# i just want to show the latest 10 tags sorted by tag.resources.count

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, controller

this will show up in the sidebar, that is why i put it in application controller. im open to a better solution

```
class ApplicationController < ActionController::Base

  protect_from_forgery

  before_filter :get_tags_latest, :get_tags_popular

  def get_tags_latest
    @tags_latest = Tag.all.first(5)
  end

  def get_tags_popular
    @tags_popular = Tag.by_most_resources.limit(10)
  end

end
```

tag.rb:

```
class Tag < ActiveRecord::Base

  self.include_root_in_json = false

  has_many :resource_tags
  has_many :resources, :through => :resource_tags

  attr_accessible :name

  validates :name, :presence => true,
                   :length   => { :within => 2..20 },
                   :uniqueness => { :case_sensitive => false }

  scope :by_most_resources,
    joins("INNER JOIN resources ON resources.tag_id = tags.id").
    group("tags.*").order("count(resources.id) DESC")

end
```

sidebar.html.erb

```
<ul class="tag-list">
    <% @tags_popular.each do |t| %>
      <li><%= link_to t.name, tag_path(t), :class => :tag %> (<%= t.resources.count %>)</li>
    <% end %>
  </ul>
```

I don't have much code at the moment (hopefully its in the right spot too)... really all I want to do is show the most popular 10 tags sorted by tag.resources.count, as well as the latest 5 tags sorted by date. I tried looking around for find(:order => ) but that proved unhelpful.

Is there a magical way to do this? Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Starting with the SQL

```
SELECT tags.*
FROM tags
  INNER JOIN resources ON resources.tag_id = tags.id
GROUP BY tags.*
ORDER BY count(resources.id) DESC
LIMIT 10
```

so, to ActiveRecordize this...

```
class Tag < ActiveRecord::Base
  scope :by_most_resources,
    joins("INNER JOIN resources ON resources.tag_id = tags.id").
    group("tags.*").order("count(resources.id) DESC")
```

call this by:

```
Tag.by_most_resources.limit(10)
```

Comment: is this the same for sqlite3?

Comment: SQLite3::SQLException: near "*": syntax error: SELECT  "tags".* FROM "tags" INNER JOIN resources ON resources.tag_id = tags.id GROUP BY tags.* ORDER BY count(resources.id) DESC LIMIT 10

Comment: Any idea? I feel im so close because that was such a great answer :/

Comment: You didn't mess with the select did you?  The SELECT clause is wrong because it does not list fields.  You don't need the select method call in the chain.

Comment: @Tallboy I think Markdown ate your comment, there are supposed to be two stars there surrounding the now italic text. As for the error, my guess is SQLite doesn't support `GROUP BY tags.*`. Try using `GROUP BY tags.id` instead?

Comment: SQLite3::SQLException: no such column: resources.tag_id

Comment: would it be unadvisable to just use sort and collect somehow?

Comment: Before your edit, you had Tags has_many Resources.  For a many to many, you need to join through the resource_tags table too.

scope :by_most_resources,
    joins("INNER JOIN resource_tags ON resource_tags.tag_id = tags.id INNER JOIN resources ON resource_tags.resource_id = resources.id").
    group("tags.*").order("count(resources.id) DESC")

Comment: sort and collect should work OK.  I know sort is good.  I never used collect, especially with ActiveRecord.  If it works anywhere, it should work here.

Comment: That worked. I really wish I knew WTF is going on, because theres no way i could reproduce that...

Comment: It takes learning and getting used to what you can do with SQL. :)